# Как вывести доступные форматы веб-камеры и установить нужный

Tags: delphi, web-camera, directshow

Нашел в сети пример проекта, по перехвату видео с веб-камеры. В нем все хорошо, но мне нужно вывести все доступные форматы камеры combobox и выбрав нужный установить этот формат.

```
var
  Form1: TForm1;
  IniFile: TIniFile;
  DeviceName: OleVariant;
  PropertyName: IPropertyBag;
  pDevEnum: ICreateDEvEnum;
  pEnum: IEnumMoniker;
  pMoniker: IMoniker;

  MArray1: array of IMoniker; // Это список моникеров, из которго
  // мы потом будем получать необходмый моникер

  // интерфейсы
  FGraphBuilder: IGraphBuilder;
  FCaptureGraphBuilder: ICaptureGraphBuilder2;
  FMux: IBaseFilter;
  FSink: IFileSinkFilter;
  FMediaControl: IMediaControl;
  FVideoWindow: IVideoWindow;
  FVideoCaptureFilter: IBaseFilter;
  FAudioCaptureFilter: IBaseFilter;
  // область вывода изображения
  FVideoRect: TRect;

  FBaseFilter: IBaseFilter;
  FSampleGrabber: ISampleGrabber;
  MediaType: AM_MEDIA_TYPE;


function TForm1.Initializ: HResult;
begin
  // Создаем объект для перечисления устройств
  Result := CoCreateInstance(CLSID_SystemDeviceEnum, NIL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
    IID_ICreateDevEnum, pDevEnum);

  if Result <> S_OK then
    EXIT;

  // Перечислитель устройств Video
  Result := pDevEnum.CreateClassEnumerator(CLSID_VideoInputDeviceCategory,
    pEnum, 0);

  if Result <> S_OK then
    EXIT;
  // Обнуляем массив в списке моникеров
  setlength(MArray1, 0);
  // Пускаем массив по списку устройств
  while (S_OK = pEnum.Next(1, pMoniker, Nil)) do
  begin
    setlength(MArray1, length(MArray1) + 1); // Увеличиваем массив на единицу
    MArray1[length(MArray1) - 1] := pMoniker; // Запоминаем моникер в масиве
    Result := pMoniker.BindToStorage(NIL, NIL, IPropertyBag, PropertyName);
    // Линкуем моникер устройства к формату хранения IPropertyBag

    if FAILED(Result) then
      Continue;

    Result := PropertyName.Read('FriendlyName', DeviceName, NIL);
    // Получаем имя устройства

    if FAILED(Result) then
      Continue;

    // Добавляем имя устройства в списки
    ListBox1.Items.Add(DeviceName);
  end;

  // Первоначальный выбор устройств для захвата видео
  // Выбираем из спика камеру
  if ListBox1.Count = 0 then
  begin
    ShowMessage('Камера не обнаружена');
    Result := E_FAIL;;
    EXIT;
  end;
  ListBox1.ItemIndex := 0;
  // если все ОК
  Result := S_OK;
end;


function TForm1.CreateGraph: HResult;
var
  pConfigMux: IConfigAviMux;

begin
  // Чистим граф
  FVideoCaptureFilter := NIL;
  FVideoWindow := NIL;
  FMediaControl := NIL;
  FSampleGrabber := NIL;
  FBaseFilter := NIL;
  FCaptureGraphBuilder := NIL;
  FGraphBuilder := NIL;

  // Создаем объект для графа фильтров
  Result := CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FilterGraph, NIL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
    IID_IGraphBuilder, FGraphBuilder);
  if FAILED(Result) then
    EXIT;
  // Создаем объект для граббинга
  Result := CoCreateInstance(CLSID_SampleGrabber, NIL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
    IID_IBaseFilter, FBaseFilter);
  if FAILED(Result) then
    EXIT;
  // Создаем объект для графа захвата
  Result := CoCreateInstance(CLSID_CaptureGraphBuilder2, NIL,
    CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_ICaptureGraphBuilder2, FCaptureGraphBuilder);
  if FAILED(Result) then
    EXIT;

  // Добавляем фильтр в граф
  Result := FGraphBuilder.AddFilter(FBaseFilter, 'GRABBER');
  if FAILED(Result) then
    EXIT;
  // Получаем интерфейс фильтра перехвата
  Result := FBaseFilter.QueryInterface(IID_ISampleGrabber, FSampleGrabber);
  if FAILED(Result) then
    EXIT;

  if FSampleGrabber <> NIL then
  begin
    // Устанавливаем формат данных для фильтра перехвата
    ZeroMemory(@MediaType, sizeof(AM_MEDIA_TYPE));

    with MediaType do
    begin
      majortype := MEDIATYPE_Video;
      subtype := MEDIASUBTYPE_RGB24;
      formattype := FORMAT_VideoInfo;
    end;

    FSampleGrabber.SetMediaType(MediaType);

    // Данные будут записаны в буфер в том виде, в котором они
    // проходят через фильтр
    FSampleGrabber.SetBufferSamples(TRUE);

    // Граф не будет остановлен для получения кадра
    FSampleGrabber.SetOneShot(FALSE);
  end;

  // Задаем граф фильтров
  Result := FCaptureGraphBuilder.SetFiltergraph(FGraphBuilder);
  if FAILED(Result) then
    EXIT;

  // выбор устройств ListBox - ов
  if ListBox1.ItemIndex >= 0 then
  begin
    // получаем устройство для захвата видео из списка моникеров
    MArray1[ListBox1.ItemIndex].BindToObject(NIL, NIL, IID_IBaseFilter,
      FVideoCaptureFilter);
    // добавляем устройство в граф фильтров
    FGraphBuilder.AddFilter(FVideoCaptureFilter, 'VideoCaptureFilter');
    // Получаем фильтр графа захвата
  end;

  // Задаем, что откуда будем получать и куда оно должно выводиться
  Result := FCaptureGraphBuilder.RenderStream(@PIN_CATEGORY_PREVIEW, nil,
    FVideoCaptureFilter, FBaseFilter, nil);
  if FAILED(Result) then
    EXIT;

  // Получаем интерфейс управления окном видео
  Result := FGraphBuilder.QueryInterface(IID_IVideoWindow, FVideoWindow);
  if FAILED(Result) then
    EXIT;
  // Задаем стиль окна вывода
  FVideoWindow.put_WindowStyle(WS_CHILD or WS_CLIPSIBLINGS);
  // Накладываем окно вывода на  Panel1
  FVideoWindow.put_Owner(Panel1.Handle);
  // Задаем размеры окна во всю панель
  FVideoRect := Panel1.ClientRect;
  FVideoWindow.SetWindowPosition(FVideoRect.Left, FVideoRect.Top,
    FVideoRect.Right - FVideoRect.Left, FVideoRect.Bottom - FVideoRect.Top);
  // показываем окно
  FVideoWindow.put_Visible(TRUE);

  // Запрашиваем интерфейс управления графом
  Result := FGraphBuilder.QueryInterface(IID_IMediaControl, FMediaControl);
  if FAILED(Result) then
    EXIT;
  // Запускаем отображение просмотра с вебкамер
  FMediaControl.Run();
end;
```

Comment: Так а что, собственно, не получается? Сформулируйте вопрос.

Comment: Не получается получить список доступных форматов веб-камеры и установить необходимый.

Comment: Вы как-то пробовали получить этот список? В вашем коде из вопроса сильно "многа букав".

Comment: Да, пробовал, но все попытки оказались ошибочными. В коде я привел пример перехвата видео и его отображения, чтоб было понятно с чем я работаю.

Comment: Приведите лучше пример того как вы пытались получить список форматов. Мне кажется это будет более полезная информация. Сам я вряд ли вам помогу. Я пытаюсь помочь вам правильно задать вопрос, чтобы тот, кто в этом больше разбирается, смог вам помочь.

Comment: [Копия на большом SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49069661/868014)